# Order of Initialization of static initializers in a class

Tags: java, static, initialization

I have a class which is supposed to supply paths to the program. In order to do so, it determines the local and the roaming data path under Windows and just takes a sub directory of home under Linux. Besides that, it provides paths derived from the other ones.

Is it safe to write

```
public class DataDirectory {
    public static final File ROAMING;
    public static final File LOCAL;

    static {
        // set ROAMING and LOCAL
    }

    public static final File PROFILE =  doMkdirs(new File(ROAMING, "profiles");
    public static final File SETUP =  doMkdirs(new File(ROAMING, "setup");
    public static final File LOGFILES =  doMkdirs(new File(ROAMING, "logfiles");

    private static File doMkdirs(File file) {
        file.mkdirs();
        return file;
    }
}
```

or do I have to do

```
public class DataDirectory {
    public static final File ROAMING;
    public static final File LOCAL;

    public static final File PROFILE;
    public static final File SETUP;
    public static final File LOGFILES;

    static {
        // set ROAMING and LOCAL

        PROFILE = mkdirsRoaming("profiles");
        SETUP = mkdirsRoaming("setup");
        LOGFILES = mkdirsRoaming("logfiles");
    }

    public static final File PROFILE = doMkdirs(new File(ROAMING, "profiles");
    public static final File SETUP = doMkdirs(new File(ROAMING, "setup");
    public static final File LOGFILES = doMkdirs(new File(ROAMING, "logfiles");

    private static File doMkdirs(File file) {
        file.mkdirs();
        return file;
    }
}
```

on order to be safe?

Answer (score 0):

I answer this question by myself in QA style.

The java specs state that [the initializers are executed in textual order, as though they were a single block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2).

That means that the first version is safe; the initializers after the `static { }` block can make use of the final variables set up inside that block.